# How can I upload multiple pdf files in different sections to the website?

Tags: php, html, pdf, upload

I would like to make accessible to my website's users pdf files, therefore I need to upload these pdf files to my website : I have a folder in my desktop that has more than 50 folders (listed by country ) in every folder there's 10 folders (listed by law sectors) wherein there's the pdf files that I would like to upload to the correspondent country web page. for now am doing this by using html :

```
 <li><a href="path file in my desktop" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Name of the file</a></li>.
```

is there a way to do this better and smarter?
I have been told I could this better by using pathinfo and foreach loop but I couldn't figure it how? please help

[this is how I would like to add pdf files to my website by adding clickable links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UdEW.jpg)

Comment: You will have to upload all these directories and files to the server. They cannot be accessed from your personal PC unless you keep a server running there as well

Comment: I apologize I am quite new to this so can u show me how to upload these directories to the server?

Comment: I cannot show you, but your Hosting Company normally provide a Admin Panel of some sort. On there I would expect to see some reference to FTP.

Comment: thank you for your reply! so once I purchase the domain name( +hosting) I will have access to FTP where I can store my files easily and upload them to every country's web page accordingly ?

Comment: Yes I would expect so

Comment: quick question please: I am not planning on dumping pdf files in every country web page but I would like to add clickable pdf files in every section of the country web page; would that be possible through FTP?

Comment: No, ftp just lets you upload (or download) files to your servers file structure